# R - Changing the data in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

```
row.names   CLIMATE_IDENTIFIER  STN_ID  ENG_STN_NAME    DRY_BULB_TEMP   RELATIVE_HUMIDITY   DEW_POINT_TEMP  WIND_SPEED  WIND_DIRECTN_16 WIND_CHILL  LOCAL_YEAR  LOCAL_MONTH LOCAL_DAY   LOCAL_HOUR
1   170 8203428 49109   MARTOCK 35M -1.4    86  -3.5    0   NA  12.24   2011    2   12  19
2   199 8203428 49109   MARTOCK 35M -1.9    87  -3.7    0   NA  11.93   2011    2   12  19
3   262 8203428 49109   MARTOCK 35M -0.3    94  -1.2    0   NA  12.93   2011    2   14  7
4   263 8203428 49109   MARTOCK 35M 1.1 83  -1.4    0   NA  13.80   2011    2   14  13
5   280 8203428 49109   MARTOCK 35M -0.7    90  -2.2    0   NA  12.68   2011    2   14  10
6   299 8203428 49109   MARTOCK 35M 2.0 79  -1.3    0   NA  14.36   2011    2   14  12
7   318 8203428 49109   MARTOCK 35M -1.6    94  -2.4    0   NA  12.12   2011    2   14  9
8   347 8203428 49109   MARTOCK 35M 1.7 98  1.4 0   NA  14.17   2011    2   15  0
9   402 8203428 49109   MARTOCK 35M 3.3 91  2.0 0   NA  15.17   2011    2   15  3
10  419 8203428 49109   MARTOCK 35M 3.1 94  2.2 0   NA  15.04   2011    2   15  3
11  567 8203428 49109   MARTOCK 35M -3.7    56  -11.2   0   NA  10.82   2011    2   16  18
12  587 8203428 49109   MARTOCK 35M -4.9    60  -11.4   0   NA  10.07   2011    2   16  20
```

There's an example of my data.

I'm looking to replace all values in the column `WIND_CHILL` with 
`DRY_BULB_TEMP + ((-1.59+0.1345*DRY_BULB_TEMP)/5)*WIND_SPEED` but only when `WIND_SPEED < 5`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is very basic. You can assign to a subset in R. Just read a tutorial or introduction to R.

Comment: I don't want a subset though, I would like the data in the original column to be overwritten so when I go to graph it all points are graphed. Also how did you edit the code to make it look like that?

Comment: (you can inspect the edit history to see the changes)

Comment: And "assign to a subset" is not the same thing as "taking a subset".

Answer (score 2):

As @Roland pointed out, it's basic subsetting:

```
i <- dat$WIND_SPEED < 5
dat[i,]$WIND_CHILL <- dat[i,]$DRY_BULB_TEMP + 
                      ((-1.59+0.1345 * dat[i,]$DRY_BULB_TEMP) / 5) * 
                       dat[i,]$WIND_SPEED
```

You may want to peruse some of the introductory R resources in the [SO R Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info)